# How to configure user -> OpenVPN -> Tor -> OpenVPN with Whonix

Tags: networking, virtualbox, proxy, openvpn, tor

My question is as follows:

I have host OS windows 7. What i want to configure such a connection: Host (with OpenVPN connected) - > VirtualBox - > Whonix-Gateway with Whonix-Workstation or with any other OS (i prefer XP) and with another OpenVPN connection. So we will have such a chain of connection: Me with OpenVPN - > Tor - > OpenVPN.

So, could please tell me how to do step by step such a configuration or this configuration is possible at all?

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused a little, you described two different connection setups.

It would be better for you to do this instead.

```
<-----VirtualBox VM's------->
You(WhonixClient)  (WhonixGW) (Win7 OpenVPN)   (VPN Endpoint)
  |---Normal Whonix---|   |------|        |-------|      |----->Tor-Entry-Node
```

WhonixClient & WhonixGW: normal whonix setup

Windows7 OpenVPN client, set to transparently route ALL traffic over a VPN. All vpn traffic exits at the vpn server, and since your running whonix, enters a tor entry node from that point.

If you run a VPN client from inside Whonix-Client, that will route over Tor, and exit the VPN endpoint.  But doing that after the other layers destroys the anonymity you gained from tor.